# Jquery Click event with javascript callback is gertting executed more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
    function MyConfirm(message, callback) {
            console.log("In My Confirm");
            var ids = document.getElementById("mymodal");
            $('#MyText').html(message);
           
            ids.style.display = "block"
           
            $('input[id^=cfrm_]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("In Click Event");
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback($(this).attr('value'));
                }
                ids.style.display = "none"
            });            
        }

        var as="My Test Message";

        function mytest(){
            var na = MyConfirm(as, function (result) {
                console.log("Result: "+result)
            });

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="mytest()" value="button" /></div>
       <div id="mymodal" style="display:none">
            <div id="MyText"></div>
            <input id="cfrm_btnYes" type="button" value="Yes" />
            <input id="cfrm_btnNo" type="button" value="No" />
        
           </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the above code to mimic the default confirm dialog window action. The function is working fine. But upon clicking the the button mytest() is called and it makes the  div #mymodal visible with two buttons as expected. But when you click the Yes or No button it makes the div hidden but it loops through the MyConfirm function multiple times. It can be seen in console. Can any one please explain me why I am getting this weird response. My aim is to create an alternate for confirm() fn. with a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you bind a new `click` event to confirm buttons **each** time `MyConfirm()` function executes. `click` event binding doesn't override old bindings but adds a new function to that event.

You can add `$('input[id^=cfrm_]').off('click');` to delete old bindings before binding new one.

```js
function MyConfirm(message, callback) {
            console.log("In My Confirm");
            var ids = document.getElementById("mymodal");
            $('#MyText').html(message);
           
            ids.style.display = "block"
           
            $('input[id^=cfrm_]').off('click');
           
            $('input[id^=cfrm_]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("In Click Event");
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback($(this).attr('value'));
                }
                ids.style.display = "none"
            });            
        }

        var as="My Test Message";

        function mytest(){
            var na = MyConfirm(as, function (result) {
                console.log("Result: "+result)
            });

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="mytest()" value="button" /></div>
       <div id="mymodal" style="display:none">
            <div id="MyText"></div>
            <input id="cfrm_btnYes" type="button" value="Yes" />
            <input id="cfrm_btnNo" type="button" value="No" />
        
           </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `return`.  Maybe it will be ready.